# Definición de "caja"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

Cuando alguien menciona la palabra *caja*, en el sentido más básico de la misma:

> 1. f. Recipiente que, cubierto con una tapa suelta o unida a la parte principal, sirve para guardar o transportar en él algo.

yo siempre pienso en un recipiente con forma de paralelepípedo. Sin embargo, en la definición no aparece reflejada restricción alguna en cuanto a la forma del mismo. Pero no puedo evitar usar otras palabras si el recipiente tiene otra forma, como *cubo* si es cilíndrico (aunque tenga tapa), *baúl* si la tapa es convexa, etc. En versiones anteriores del diccionario se menciona expresamente

> de materia y forma variables

o

> es de varias formas y tamaños

Y una vez más, si veo una caja con otra forma que no sea la rectangular me siento raro usando la palabra *caja*.

¿Soy yo, o es lo habitual? ¿Alguien podría ponerme algún ejemplo en el que el uso de *caja* con este significado no suene raro con formas de caja distintas a la rectangular? ¿O es simplemente que unas definiciones contienen a otras y un *baúl* no deja de ser un tipo de *caja*?

Comment: Las típicas cajas de sombreros de las películas o las cajas de bombones con forma de corazón.

Comment: Caja de ahorros, caja de Pandora (que en realidad era una ánfora)

Comment: Una caja de herramientas. La caja de resonancia de ciertos instrumentos musicales (como la guitarra).
Yo diría que un baúl no es una caja. Claro, que si has leído El hobbit, sabrás que un huevo también es una caja.
Cuando yo pienso en una caja, siempre me viene un paralelepípedo a la mente, además fabricado de cartón ondulado (si tiene tapa) o de listones de madera (si no la tiene).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que varios objetos sirvan para lo mismo no los hace iguales. En principio yo también pienso que un baúl no es una caja aunque ambos sean contenedores por lo que en pareciera que estamos de acuerdo.

Sin embargo si miramos las definiciones en la RAE encontramos ejemplos como "caja torácica", que existe un tambor que se llama caja, que la parte del vehiculo donde se transporta la carga se llama caja (cajuela en algunas partes), que la parte de madera exterior del piano también es una caja, y muchos más.

En resumen, la definición de caja no la limita a la forma de paralelepípedo.

El ejemplo que creo es más extremo es el de "Caja torácica" pero también están las cajas típicas en las que se guardan los sombreros que son de forma cilíndrica.

[image]

También están estas otras que *no cuesta tanto trabajo* llamarlas cajas.
[image]

o esta (gracias Julio Codesal)

[image: o esta (gracias Julio Codesal)]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. Desde luego, el uso de _caja_ para guardar sombreros o bombones está extendido. Sin embargo, existen las palabras sombrerero y bombonera para estos menesteres. Y la caja octogonal parece un joyero. La caja torácica es a su vez un tipo especial de caja. Todos los ejemplos son cajas, sí, pero su propósito particular hace que existan otros términos. Sin embargo, si nos vamos a la definición básica, la de contenedor genérico que no almacena nada concreto y que no se puede usar otra palabra para describirlo, ese es el que se me antoja siempre rectangular.